# Restart Function After List Is X Length

Tags: python, python-3.x

Please help me out.

I have a RPi connected up to a sound sensor. Every time the detector is activated, a string gets inserted into a list.

What I want to do, is restart the whole process once the list is 7 units long. See my code below.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
pin = 7 #Defining pin 7 as Input pin
GPIO.setup(pin, GPIO.IN)

list = ["Start"]

while l:
    if GPIO.input(pin) == GPIO.LOW: #This is the input
        if len(list) <= 6:
            list.insert(0, "Entry") #Insert into list at first position
            print ("Not Done")
            print (len(list))

        elif len(list) > 6:
            print ("Done")

#This is where I want it to go back to the list being 1 unit long.
```

So, as you can see, when the list is 7 units long, the function is done. So now, I want it to restart and go back to the list being 1 unit long again. How do I do that? Been battling for days.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the list to its initial value.

```
elif len(list) > 6:
    list = ["Start"]
    print ("Done")
```